# How to post a json?

Tags: javascript, html, json, post

```
{
"entry": 
   {
      "city_id": "1234",
      "city_name": "California"
   }
}
```

Consider this is the json i want to post from my html form to the content management system api. I have a form with two text boxes for getting the entry of city_id and city_name and one submit button.

I need the above json to go as input to the api through post. I want to do it in javascript.
Kindly help me

Comment: Some code would be nice!

Comment: well you can post the data as a simple form, and then encode it on the server side before sending it the CMS API, rather than sending it as a JSON string!

Comment: what's the server-side language you are using? php?

Answer (score 2):

What does your API look like?

POST is a HTTP action and the HTTP protocol doesn't know about JSON.

---

If you know that you need to supply a JSON value through HTTP, chances are that you'll need to `JSON.stringify()` your JSON object and then pass that string as a named POST parameter, but this is a guess. Your API should tell you exactly how it wants the data passed.

If that's insufficient, I can continue if you provide more details.

Comment: Indeed, I've very rarely seen JSON being sent to the server. Actually,  I've only seen [one API](http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/rest_api/introduction.html) to require that. (Which then did not use any parameter name, simply a `curl <url> -d '{ "entry": { "city_id": "1234", "city_name": "California" } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -X POST` would do there.)

Comment: I've setup a few apis using NodeJS that accept json as the body of a POST without requiring parameterisation. It's not really 'standard' but it works quite nicely if you're just pushing JSON around.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible jQuery code for an AJAX request with custom form data:

```
var form = $('#myform');
var data = {
    mail: form.find('input[name=mail]').val(),
    pass: form.find('input[name=pass]').val(),
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : '/foo/bar',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : data,
    success : function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // do something with the result
    },
});
```

Comment: Nope, that is not *sending* JSON to the server.

Comment: that's right, i misunderstood the question. nevertheless it shouldn't be necessary to send JSON since the POST data can easily be converted

Comment: Actually, maybe I misread too; the OP is not saying it should be JSON in the request as well. (The downvote wasn't mine; +1 to make up for that, but you might want to explain that this is not sending the data as JSON, despite for example the `dataType` that many confuse for the type of the request?)

Comment: Entry POST /accounts/:account_id/collections/:collection_id/entries Entry Representation Entry Representation Create a new Entry

Comment: @user1409314, please use the "edit" link below your question to add such details. (And while editing, peek in the formatting help!)